# Taskbar not working after Windows updates

Tags: windows, windows-8, taskbar

My taskbar is not working after I install all Windows updates. Now when I on am on the laptop, a shield-like icon appears in the taskbar. I am using windows 8.

Nothing happens when when I click on the icon:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmiun.png]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like UAC's running, but for some reason, the overlay isn't visible. This happens some times. Alt tab to bring UAC to the front, handle whatever its prompting you about and things should be back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like user account control. It would be asking you to give permission to update the system. Right click on it, close it, and update the system again. It should come up automatically. If it does not, then click on nit.